# How to Terminate the effect of function before the other starts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to show few random posts at the end of each single post. I found this code for this purpose.

```
    <div>
<h2>Random Posts</h2>
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'offset' => 1);
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

But the problem is that when I use this code on my site, it also cause the random output of next and previous post links present at the bottom of each post for better navigation.

I want to know how to terminate the effect of random posts so that pre and next post links are displayed in their original order.

Comment: I couldn't quite understand what the actual problem is. Is it that the next/prev post links that you display after each post are messed up/incorrect? If so, try the following code instead: `foreach( $rand_posts as $_post ) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php get_permalink($_post->ID); ?>"><?php get_the_title($_post->ID); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: First your code is not working for me.

Comment: Every single post contains two links at the bottom of the page: one pointing to next entry(post) and other pointing to previous entry(post). But when I use the above code to generate random post on any post, those links are also randomized instead of showing the exact next post link and previous post link.

Comment: Yeah, my problem was that I forgot to use `echo` in front of the `get_` functions. Otherwise it should work properly. What I think was happening with your code was that you were overwriting the `$post` variable. Anyway `wp_reset_query()` works as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

More info here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query